# App working on my device but when I publish it to Google Play Store for Beta Testing not working

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, beta-testing

Yesterday I published my app on the Google Play Store as Beta Testing. When I run it from Eclipse on my device it works great, but when I download it from the Google Play Store it doesn't work.

The first screen is an Splash Fragment which shows the Facebook Login button, when I click it it asks for the permissions and then it goes back to the Splash Fragment (It should hide the Fragment).

I tested it on another device and it hides the Splash Fragment, enters to the MainActivity and it tells me that I am not online.

I don't underestand why it does work when I run it from my Eclipse but it doesn't work when I run the version that I download from the Google Play Store.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tokensapp.tokens"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission
    android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".ScrumptiousApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/tokens" >
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />

    <service android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.NotificationService" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.apphance.android.LauncherActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.apphance.android.ui.LoginActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.apphance.android.ui.TestCycleActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.apphance.android.ui.ProblemActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActSplash"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActLoginFb"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActWelcome"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActMain"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActMain2"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActProfile"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActCompose"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActViewToken"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActSettings"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActFriendChooser"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.BasicMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />

    <receiver android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActLoginFb2"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.apphance.android.LAUNCH" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="PickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tokensapp.tokens.ActMyTokens"
        android:label="@string/tokens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name=".ApphanceLauncherActivity"
        android:targetActivity="com.apphance.android.LauncherActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
</application>

<instrumentation
    android:name="com.apphance.android.ApphanceInstrumentation"
    android:targetPackage="com.tokensapp.tokens" >
</instrumentation>
```

Comment: Any logcat warnings or errors?

Comment: Nothing, the Logcat looks fine

Comment: Now, I fixed the Facebook part. I was missing the hash key of the new keystore. But now I can't see the map, I am using Google Maps API V2. I get this error at the Logcat "Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the api console"

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps requires that the API key be built to the Application Signing Key.  That means that the Maps API key you use for debugging (running through Eclipse) will be different than the Maps API key which will work on apps exported from Eclipse and signed to post on the Play Store.  All you need to do is get an updated Maps API key using the same key you sign your app with!

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385211/android-google-maps-v2-debug-key-vs-release-key) for a method of creating one Maps API key for both Debug and Release versions of your signed package.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your facebook app is in live mode.

Comment: What do you mean about that. What's sandbox mode?

Comment: @MartiSerraMolina you need to switch your facebook app to live mode (in 2013 it default to sandbox mode that only work on debug version. but this answer is now obsolete