# Saving the API Key in gradle.properties

Tags: android, api

I am new to android and working on a project where I see that the API key that I got is saved in `gradle.properties` as :

`MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey="1c3ae96f93a0094e8a7chsjdgfid04aed3f10"`

And then in `build.gradle(module:app)` I am adding the following lines :

```
buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey
      }
```

So, in my main program I am accessing the data using this api whose URL is got by this piece of code :

```
final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
            final String APPID_PARAM = "APPID";
            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY)
                    .build();
            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
```

So, my question is that why taking all the tension of doing changes to store the appid in the gradle part. Can't we access directly in the main program only ?

And the second part of my question is what is actually happening in the gradle part especially with the `buildTypes.each{}` block ?

Comment: Thanks. Your question helped me to configure my project.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. The idea of this indirection is to allow you to store API key in files that are not uploaded to the version control: `gradle.properties` is a local file and should not be stored under the version control, and `BuildConfig` is a generated class, so it will only be created at build time. It's definitely easier to store the API key somewhere as a plain String, but then you'll have to commit it to the repo.
2. During build time, Gradle will generate the `BuildConfig` file to store some build-related constants. You can use `buildConfigField` command to instruct Gradle to add custom fields into `BuildConfig`. After the project is built, you can reference these constants inside your source code.

Comment: Is it safe from reverse engineering on apk?

Comment: @SumitShukla, it is not, the API key will still end up being a constant string that can easily be located upon decompilation. If you want some value to be safe from reverse engineering then it should live on the server.

Comment: Other similar ways that you can follow:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134031/is-there-a-safe-way-to-manage-api-keys

Comment: If you put your API_KEY in your app, then you need to enable proguard to so that the key would be obfuscated. Otherwise a better approach to secure your api_keys is to save them in your server and get it during the runtime.

Comment: @SonuSanjeev, I don't think proguard has a way to obfuscate string literals, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Egor, Thanks for pointing it out. A quick googling thought me proguard obfuscates class names, method names and variable names but not the strings.

Answer (score 49):

Refer - Complete implementation for storing API_KEY in gradle properties to avoid uploading to Github.

https://richardroseblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/29/hiding-secret-api-keys-from-git/

---

1. Add `gradle.properties` into `.gitignore` file
2. Add line in `gradle.properties` file `API_KEY="CopyYourAPI_KEYhere"`
3. Add below line in `app/build.gradle` within the `defaultConfig`

   `buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", API_KEY)`
4. Use Key using the following statement

   `String API_KEY = BuildConfig.API_KEY;`

Copy this wherever you need API_KEY

It will save your efforts to add and remove API_KEY while committing code in Github.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Sure, I have added the details in short. If you have any query, please let me know.

Comment: this answer is easy to understand than others, thanks :)

Comment: This method requires that you remember to add the file to your .gitignore AND remove it from git since it's added by default. Furthermore the project-level file has other settings that you DO want to share with your team. It has its own issues, but the GLOBAL gradle.properties file is better for sensitive keys.

Comment: What if you want to use the KEY on a different module?

Answer (score 16):

Saving the API Key in gradle.properties might not be a great idea. Using the local.properties file will be more convincing. Since local.properties file will by default be added in the git ignore file, I believe this will be a great place to add the API key.

To add the API_key in local properties you can follow these two simple steps below.

**Step 1**

Edit your local.properties file and add below code

```
sdk.dir=/Users/Library/Android/sdk
API_KEY=**Your Key**
```

**Step 2**

Edit your app-level build.gradle file and add the 'buildConfigField' inside `defaultConfig` as shown below.

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"${properties.getProperty('API_KEY')}\""
```

Note that [per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30796601/918858) you will need to add quotes for String types

**Step 3**

Sync your project with Gradle changes.

**Step 4**

Rebuild your project from Build->Rebuild Project.

**All done!!** Now you can access the key by calling `BuildConfig.API_KEY`

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way

First make sure both build/ and local.properties are added to your .gitignore

```
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
```

Add your APIKEY xyz123 to your local.properties as follows

```
apiKey="xyz123"
```

Next add the following block to the root level of your app build.gradle

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
def localProperties = new Properties()
localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
```

Add the following line to the android block of your app build.gradle

```
buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", localProperties['apiKey'])
```

Then, we may call the BuildConfig.API_KEY constant as follows

```
import app.unicornapp.mobile.android.unicorn.BuildConfig
import app.unicornapp.mobile.android.unicorn.BuildConfig.API_KEY
import retrofit2.http.Query


interface StockApi {
    suspend fun getListings(
        @Query("apikey") apiKey: String
    )

    companion object {
        val API_KEY = BuildConfig.API_KEY
    }

}
```

Comment: Since Android Gradle Plugin 8.0, the `BuildConfig` class is not generated by default.  
You can generate it by adding:  

`buildFeatures {
buildConfig true
}` to `build.gradle`