# how can I hide links within an app?

Tags: android

hi I have an application running online and there are links in the server but the problem is that there are people who remove the application and take the links and implement them on the browser and become a problem within the application Is there a way to hide links?

Comment: Where are the links you want to hide? In the UI? In the code? Is the code public and you just need to hide them from the public code?

Comment: example : Picasso.with(context).load("http://roman-android.com/" + View_stories.files + "/" + stories.images_view).into(holder.img_view);

Comment: I'm working on it. I know how to do it but I'm trying to remember a key step lol

Comment: ok can you help me please :D

Comment: Done, hope it's clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you wrote in comments, suppose you have this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("roman-android.com/" + View_stories.files + "/" + stories.images_view).into(holder.img_view);
```

You need to hide `roman-android.com/`.

You can do this way:

Open your `gradle.properties` file in your Android project. This file should be secret and not available online.

In `gradle.properties` write your link:

```
mySecretLink="roman-android.com/"
```

Go to your `build.gradle(module:app)` file and add, under `android`, this:

```
buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField "String" , "MY_SECRET_LINK", mySecretLink
    }
```

so that you'll have something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        //blah blah stuff
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField "String" , "MY_SECRET_LINK", mySecretLink
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    //blah blah stuff
}
```

This will tell gradle to add your `String` to the `BuildConfig` class, that is generated on build time and completely external to your code.

Go to your code and just do this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(BuildConfig.MY_SECRET_LINK + View_stories.files + "/" + stories.images_view).into(holder.img_view);
```

**NOTE**: I've tried to explain [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722904/saving-the-api-key-in-gradle-properties) and to adapt it in your situation. I based my explanation on an old code of mine where I did this to conceal my API key.

Obviously you need to keep secret the `gradle.properties` file. You'll use its real values only at compilation time, keeping aliases for your secred information (such as `MY_SECRET_LINK`) for the whole programming process.

Comment: In your android studio project. If you set the view mode to "android" (upper left corner of the project tab) it should be under "gradle"

Comment: I found it :D , but anyone can open this file gradle.properties and see it

Comment: Well anyone on the machine you're building from. This method conceals the data if you're showing your code publicly. If someone has access to the whole project he could see the links, but that's for every stored string in your app...

Comment: well when doing reverse engineering you will not see the file?

Comment: Yes you could, as for any app. I thought your problem was bound to concealing data from the code. If you need to protect your app from reverse engineering (although there's no 100% secure way) check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13854425/3626078

Comment: I don't have experience in any of that but according to that, I suggest you to look up "ProGuard" from Google

Comment: do not just links :D

Comment: I said I have no experience in that. No offense but I cannot study that for you and write a tutorial :D

Comment: but you said when writing his code in a file gradle.properties and reverse engineering work will show this file or not this is my only question :D

Comment: I don't know if the file itself will show or not... It could, or the value could be present in the decompiled code (where the value is used, inside the Picasso method). I don't have experience of reverse engineering so I don't know. All I can tell you is that my method will conceal the data from the source code, but I don't know how easy or hard it would be to recover the same value from a decompiled APK.

Comment: If you asked for a way to conceal the links from the source code my answer can help. If you asked how to protect your links in any way including reverse engineering it's not, and I suggested you some stuff to look into for that, I can't do more because I have never faced this problem and I do not have experience in this as I do with just concealing from source code

Comment: did you try to decompiling apk because this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use Authentication so no one can access your links without a password.

Comment: Is there an example of youtube please ?

Comment: I have applications on the google play with a lot of users but there are people who are sabotaging I hope to find a solution

Comment: I just want to hide links