# How to hide private stuff like API keys in GitHub for Android (android studio) project?

Tags: android, github

I am new to GitHub and working on an Android project. I have a public repository on GitHub and the project also contains some private stuff like API keys etc. How do I hide those in my project from public. At the same time, I want that the data must be available to the collaborators (my project team members are the collaborators).

Comment: git ignore the files with the keys and share the keys some other way.

Comment: The key is in a .java file (as a String) and it is being shown in my project

Comment: Check out the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134031/is-there-a-safe-way-to-manage-api-keys) question