# Where to put api-key at production environment? not putting it in local.properties

Tags: android, android-studio, api-key

If I give source code of Android app to client and only client have google map api key.Where is the good place put api-key in android studio to fetch api-key which I don't know?Also Jenkins can build this project without local.properties.(API-Key not put in local.properties)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a safe way to manage API keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134031/is-there-a-safe-way-to-manage-api-keys)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Client can't modify android app file. So I think your link not the answer but thank you.

Comment: Can't your client edit the XML file as suggested there?