# How to use gradle to replace Google Maps API key?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I use one among many options to store my API keys in the **computer/keychain** rather than directly in the cloud-backed-up project code (namely [gradle-credentials-plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-credentials-plugin) ). What I'd like is to be able to manage Google Maps keys in a similar way, but they're used in a different file ([Manage Google Maps API Key with Gradle in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124309/manage-google-maps-api-key-with-gradle-in-android-studio)).

If anyone has a simple (or intricate, but reliable) option for me to dig into, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Why can't you use the combination of the two things that you linked to? Use `credentials.whateverYouCallYourMapsApiKey` to populate `resValue`.

Comment: Do you think couldn't be enough having different string key for the different build variant "release" and "debug"?

Comment: @shadowsheep I fail to see how that would store the keys in the computer, avoiding sending it into the public repository?

Comment: It should be a good solution to have let's say a file named `api.keys` in which you have your keys and that you ignore so that is not versioned and that you have only in your PC? So that to get your production key in the release build and your development key in the debug build?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I'll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadowsheep's solution works, but it's not really what I want to do.

What I've ended up doing.

- First, I was under the mistaken impression it was absolutely necessary to populate *google-maps-api.xml* with the key, when it apparently is sufficient to set the key in the Manifest.
- Second, I've added a `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value"@string/GoogleMapsApiKey">` line into the Manifest
- Third, I've set mapsKey via my chosen tool (gradle-credentials-plugin by etiennestuder)
- Finally, I've added into the app's module *build.gradle* `buildTypes` section these two lines:

> def mapsKey = credentials.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY ?: "Key Missing"
>
> it.resValue "string", "GoogleMapsApiKey", mapsKey

Answer (score 11):

You can use [manifestPlaceholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) to inject the string from your `build.gradle`.

1. Inset your API key into a file like `local.properties`

```
google.maps_api_key=SECRET_KEY
```

2. Make sure this file is ignored using `.gitignore`:

```
local.properties
```

3. Make the API key available to your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Using `withInputStream()` ensures the `InputStream` [is closed automatically](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html).

```
android{
  defaultConfig {

    // Load credentials.
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("../local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }

    // Share the key with your `AndroidManifest.xml`
    manifestPlaceholders = [ googleMapsApiKey:"${properties.getProperty('google.maps_api_key')}"]
```

4. Load the API key in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${googleMapsApiKey}" />
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this out next time I encounter this situation!

Comment: Thank you! your recommendations worked for me! Before I found it I had tried to use recommendations by Google found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key,  but they didn't work because they didn't say anything about "manifestPlaceholders".

Comment: Instead of local.properties, I use gradle.properties to store the key, because local.properties file is excluded in .gitignore, and so it is loss of information to the developers. Can I use your solution?

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena Should work, but it's on purpose to exclude `local.properties` from git as you usually don't want to store sensitive information in the repository (here: Google Map Key). Even if you repo is private, you (or a fork of yours) might set it to public at some point and then the key can be retrieved from Git history by others. But that's no topic to be discussed in this comment section :).

Comment: It worked! (Although the following is out of topic, still adding) The file local.properties take the path of Android and Native SDK for one machine. It does not make sense, to share it, if other developers are to contribute in the same project. Though Android Studio corrects the wrong paths itself on the start of the project, but still. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a **not versioned** file called as you want, let's say `api.keys` with this content:

```
debugMapsApiKey=xxxxXXXxxxx
releaseMapsApiKey=xxxYYYxxx
```

Put it in your root project folder.

You read this file in your `build.gradle` file in a way like that:

```
def apiKeysFile = rootProject.file("api.keys")
def apiKeysFile = new Properties()
apiKeysFile.load(new FileInputStream(apiKeysFile))

[...]

debug {
    buildConfigField "String", MAPS_KEY, apiKeysFile['debugMapsApiKey']
}

release {
    buildConfigField "String", MAPS_KEY, apiKeysFile['releaaseMapsApiKey']
}
```

And you can access it in code through

`BuildConfig.MAPS_KEY` that if you build in debug you will have `"xxxxXXxxxx"` value, instead in release you will have `"xxxxYYxxxx"`.

And if you want to access on XML you could use `resValue` that create a string resource.

```
debug {
    resValue "string", MAPS_KEY, apiKeysFile['debugMapsApiKey']
}

release {
   resValue "string", MAPS_KEY, apiKeysFile['releaseMapsApiKey']
}
```

In this way you could also get it in code with

```
getString(R.string.MAPS_KEY)
```

Comment: Well, it does work, but it doesn't quite do what I want because it ignores the tool I've set up for other keys. Upvoted, but I'll fix things a bit differently.

Comment: @Kheldar Well, I don't know what tool you have set for other keys, but If this solution helped you going through the right solution if you like you can accept it as the right answer non the less. BTW it's up to you! I'm happy you did your work done! ;)

Comment: thanks a bunch, it definitely helped me narrow down my reasoning ^^

Comment: error The current scope already contains a variable of the name apiKeysFile
   @ line 4, column 5.
     def apiKeysFile = new Properties()

Answer (score 1):

google_maps_api.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">GoogleMapsApiKey</string>
</resources>
```

manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/GoogleMapsApiKey"/>
```

gradle

```
resValue "string", "GoogleMapsApiKey", mapskey
```

gradle.properties

```
mapskey="AIza...8w" // key here
```