# Google Maps API Key - Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I currently have an API key for Google Maps Android SDK. I was unsure whether I need both a separate key for debug and release.  I saw mention of another post (linked below) stating that you CAN use the same key for both, but what are the drawbacks to this? The app will not be consumed by a large number of users, as I only intend for it to be showcase it to prospective employers.

[Android Google Maps v2 - Debug key vs Release key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385211/android-google-maps-v2-debug-key-vs-release-key)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate key. The drawback is that you can't differentiate the statistics on your Google Dev page because you don't know which request comes from debug or release.
Only matters if those statistics are really important for you to analyze.