# What SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint should I use for release build apk?

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, expo

The google map on my app only works on my DEV environment and when the apk was uploaded to store. But when I install from the release apk it doesn't work.

On my google developer console I already added 3 SHA-1 Certificate

```
1.) Debug certificate fingerprint
2.) Release certificate fingerprint (from app signing in google console)
3.) Upload certificate
```

But still not working on release apk.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your Release api key for google map API ? You must have two different api keys one for debug, one for release. You have to get a build with release api key while uploading your apk on google play. You can check here also
[Android Google Maps v2 - Debug key vs Release key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385211/android-google-maps-v2-debug-key-vs-release-key)

Comment: Thanks for this got an idea, but its working now I just got a wrong sha-1 fingerprint.